# Maximum solar irradiance per plant species

Tags: botany

I'm looking for a table or database specifying by plant species, the maximum solar irradiance it can tolerate, but seems not a straightforward search on most engines or open access botany databases. Anyone has any useful reference?

Also I'm assuming that solar irradiance and not heat, is the factor that will kill the plant via leaf burn, but maybe I'm wrong, and heat distress may kill the plant before... or impede the plant development. Any clarification on this will be useful too.

At the concrete example, I'm finding that a hazelnut (Corylus avellana) can't develop at direct sunlight in my location (middle of Spain), as its leaves seem to burn each year, as the solar radiation seems a bit too much for it. I'm planning planting the next ones at the shade of a stone pine (Pinus pinea) to relieve the irradiance from the central hours of the day (If the are good companion trees would be another question)

But you got the convenience of having this information for as much species as possible, to successfully setting plants and avoid killing them, thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Welcome Greco. For your interest: we have a [gardening.se] stack for you to enjoy too.